# How to call destructor of object on termination with Ctrl-c?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an object which I want to guarantee will be destructed even if the program is terminated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I have tried doing this using a signal handler which resets a unique pointer but I have been told that std::unique_ptr::reset is forbidden to be used in a signal handler.

```
std::unique_ptr<MotionControl> mc;

void signal_handler(int signal_num) { 
    // destruct MotionControl object and delete pointer
    mc.reset();
    // terminate program   
    exit(signal_num);   
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    try {
        std::string deviceName("/dev/ttyACM0");
        mc = std::unique_ptr<MotionControl>(new MotionControl(deviceName, 119, 65, 10));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Therefore, how can I go about doing this?

Edit 1: My OS is Ubuntu.

Edit 2: Failure to call the destructor will result in hardware damage the next time the program is run. I need to move some motion control stages to a safe location when the destructor is called.

Comment: Portable C++ knows nothing about signals. It's an OS thingy. Explore `sigset_t` and friends.

Comment: It would be good to understand the problem a little more: What kind of code is running? A loop where you can poll a flag? A different structure? Additionally, what does `~MotionControl()` actually perform? If your code fails for a more serious reason (e.g. SIGKILL or SIGSEGV), will a failure to call the destructor lead to hardware damage or physical risks anyway?

Comment: There is really very little you can do inside signal handler legally. What is the destructor actually doing?

Comment: You need to use the signal handler to somehow break the application out of its main loop. It then should terminate normally. Also I think you want to trap SIGTERM.

Comment: @Ron It's actually part of the language, a component inherited from C. See [`<csignal>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/csignal) and [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.runtime#support.signal).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Indeed so, I stand corrected.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov Yes, failure to call the destructor will result in hardware damage. I need to move some motion control stages to a safe location when the destructor is called.

Comment: @RAR If life or property depend on your cleanup, you may want to consider an out-of-context solution like a watchdog process to monitor for any unexpected termination or freeze from your critical process.

Comment: Unrelated: I find it funny that RAR, and not RUR, is working with robots.

Comment: @RAR I assume that you're not using specialized failsafe hardware and a specialized RTOS kernel. In that case, you have a bigger problem than just SIGINT handling. There are plenty of ways in which your process could stop running in a such a way that no amount of fancy usermode signal handling could ever save you. This is probably a task either handled at the other end of this serial pipe, or with dedicated failsafe hardware (and I personally would not feel confident purchasing or deploying hardware that has this risk and doesn't take such measures)

Comment: In the embedded systems I worked on, a 'warm' start ( def: code and OS reset but hardware not) inspected the hardware before changing any hardware controls.  In those systems, the running hardware was generating income, so your startup code was disallowed to interrupt the hw that was already running.  Seems like this would work for your situation.  Or does power bounce damage your hw?

Comment: If power bounce won't damage your hardware, you might decide that your startup sequence should first 'safely-shut-down-the-hw (to avoid hw damage)'.  That might be only a brief interruption of behavior.  If your requirements allow it.

Answer (score 1):

The common "zero-cost" exception implementation should let you throw out of signal handlers. It's probably quite unsafe, though, as you might corrupt some async-unsafe state. (I guess it's only safe if the signal only arrives during purely async-safe code / pure computation.)

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void signal_handler(int signal_num)
{
    throw signal_num;
}
int main()
{
    try {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT,&sa,0);

    pause();

    }catch(int X){
        printf("CAUGHT: %d\n", X);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your best bet is probably to set a global (or thread local, but I guess that's not theoretically portable either) `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag, have your regular context check it once in a while, and if it sees the flag set,
then your regular-context code may throw.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
volatile sig_atomic_t flag;
void signal_handler(int signal_num)
{
    flag = signal_num;
}
int main()
{
    try {
        struct sigaction sa;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_flags = 0;
        sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
        sigaction(SIGINT,&sa,0);

        for(;;){
            pause();
            if (flag) throw (int)flag;
        }

    }catch(int X){
        printf("CAUGHT: %d\n", X);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That was unintentional and simply happened to work. Added a cast to int.

Comment: The second code example is a good one.  The first code example will probably go poorly - don't throw from within a signal handler.

Comment: @Eljay Yeah I'm also recommending the 2nd one.  I've only mentioned the first one because at least on the Linux implementation there should be some support for asynchronous exceptions (the example works as excepted on my Linux box) but it's still fraught with nasty edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to set up a pipe or a socket-pair (using `pipe()` or `socketpair()`, respectively) at the top of `main()`, and have the signal-handler write a byte on one socket of the socket-pair (or on the sending-fd of the pipe-fd-pair).

Your main thread's event-loop should be `select()`-ing (or `poll()`-ing or whatever) on the other socket (or on the receiving-fd of the pipe-fd-pair).  When it receives a byte on that socket, the main thread should respond by gracefully shutting down the program.